# Sourceing a bash_profile does not remove commented aliases/functions

Tags: bash, shell

I edited my bash_profile to introduce some new functions and comment some existing ones. And later sourced the file to reflect the changes in the current shell. I expected the commented ones to not work, but they were still working.
I can obviously open a new shell which will load the new profile, but how can I make the current shell do that.

Comment: can you please try reset command and then source command

Comment: reset command in Linux system is used to initialize the terminal.  check this url https://linux.die.net/man/1/reset

Comment: I tried `reset` and `tset` and then source profile, but it still does not seem to work. Am i using reset wrong.

Comment: `reset` just clears the terminal and doesn't affect the shell environment.

Comment: what syntax you are using to source bash_profile file  use `. ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: both `source ~/.bash_profile` and `. ~/.bash_profile` does not work. IIRC both do the same thing right?

Comment: If you copy-pasted the contents of `~/.bash_profile` into your shell, e.g. `foo() { ..; }; bar() { ..; }`, then changed the file to `bar() { ..; }; baz() { ..; }` and copy-pasted that, would you expect `foo` to be undefined? Probably not, and that's essentially what you're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to

```sh
unset -f func1 func2 func3 ...
```

---

If you want to unset *all* functions before sourcing, you can do this:

```sh
readarray -t funcnames < <( declare -f | sed -n '/ ()[[:blank:]]*$/ s///p' )
unset -f "${funcnames[@]}"
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: works for functions. For aliases, we have to `unalias` them. But this would not be efficient if there were many aliases or functions.

Comment: You could use `exec bash -l` to switch to a new login shell. Exported data would still be available, but ephemeral things like aliases would be flushed

Comment: `exec bash -l` works in macos as well. `readarray` seems to not work in mac os.

Comment: @assassin `readarray` was added in version 4 of bash, but macOS only comes with bash v3.2 (for licensing reasons).

Comment: but with Homebrew, it's simple to add bash v5

Comment: version I am using `GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin19.4.0)`

Comment: I tried the above answer in a linux machine. It actually unset ALL functions. I couldn't event bash complete any command. Said, `function \`_filedir_xspec' not found`.  Pretty cool...